# How can I make input buttons look exactly the same in all browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm styling my form buttons like this:

```
/* CSS RESET */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
...
form input.button {
    padding: 2px;
}
...
<input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
```

But they look like this:

[image]

**What is the easiest way to make buttons look exactly the same in all browsers?**

Comment: What a great question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the **easiest** way to make buttons look **exactly the same in all browsers**?

Use an image.

I don't think you will get it **exactly** the same cross browser otherwise. You could get close with CSS, but you will be spending a bit of time and frustration (a CSS reset could make this a bit easier).

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Formalize](http://sonspring.com/journal/formalize-css).