# Mozilla / Opera input box padding

Tags: input, padding

So I made this submit button and apparently, every browser decided to make it look different. Code below works as it should only in Chrome; Opera and IE makes the button smaller; Firefox bigger. Even when I remove all paddings (editing a theme for wordpress) that could affect input box, they still look different in each browser. Workaround?

```
.search-submit  {
padding-top: 3px 7px;
color: #5e5e5e;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: normal;    
}


<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
```

Comment: You can check this question:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404708/how-can-i-make-input-buttons-look-exactly-the-same-in-all-browsers>
I hope it'll help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always start your CSS with a CSS reset to avoid the differences in the browser's native stylesheets. Eric Meyer's reset is very popular, and it has always worked for me: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Once you have the reset in place (at the very top of your css file), all browsers should display elements alike (with the same margin, padding, etc). You can pick it up from there and write the css you want for your inputs.

Comment: It's fixed in Opera and IE, but Firefox is still displaying it differently.

Comment: I eventually used an image.